# Can I make log4j use the configuration in my resources folder?

Tags: java, maven, log4j2

Getting log4j to work is way more complicated than advertised. I keep getting this error:

```
ERROR StatusLogger No log4j2 configuration file found. Using default configuration: logging only errors to the console.
```

I have tried to put my `log4j.xml` file all over the place, but what I want it is to have it in my `/resources` folder. In my `pom.xml`, these paths are defined:

```
  <properties>
    <src.dir>src/</src.dir>
    <test.dir>test/</test.dir>
    <resource.dir>resources/</resource.dir>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>
  <build>
    <testSourceDirectory>${test.dir}</testSourceDirectory>
    <sourceDirectory>${src.dir}</sourceDirectory>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>${resource.dir}</directory>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    ... long list of plugins coming, let's cut it off.
```

All resources that are in the `resources` directory are accessible from the `.jar`. There are images and icons, all working. But Log4j ignores the configuration file.

So how can I tell it where the file is and finally start actually learning to use it?

Comment: First don't start to change the defaults which makes life easier.

Comment: @khmarbaise What defaults are you reffering to?

Comment: [Maven default folder structure](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html).

Comment: @khmarbaise I was porting the project into maven. Changing existing directory structure wasn't making anything easier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using **`log4j2`**  - which requires a **`log4j2.xml`**, not `log4j.xml`.

Just rename the file, place it in the resource folder (or anywhere else in the classpath) and it should work.

Alternatevly, you can take a look at the [documentation](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html):

> 1. Log4j will inspect the "log4j.configurationFile" system property and, if set, will attempt to load the configuration using the
>      ConfigurationFactory that matches the file extension.
> 2. If no system property is set the YAML ConfigurationFactory will look for log4j2-test.yaml or log4j2-test.yml in the classpath.
> 3. If no such file is found the JSON ConfigurationFactory will look for log4j2-test.json or log4j2-test.jsn in the classpath.
> 4. If no such file is found the XML ConfigurationFactory will look for log4j2-test.xml in the classpath.
> 5. If a test file cannot be located the YAML ConfigurationFactory will look for log4j2.yaml or log4j2.yml on the classpath.
> 6. If a YAML file cannot be located the JSON ConfigurationFactory will look for log4j2.json or log4j2.jsn on the classpath.
> 7. If a JSON file cannot be located the XML ConfigurationFactory will try to locate log4j2.xml on the classpath.
> 8. If no configuration file could be located the DefaultConfiguration will be used. This will cause logging output to go to the console.

Note, however, that the log4j2 xml-configuration also has a different syntax than version 1.

Comment: Error dissapeared - thanks, I had really the file wrongly named.